# Why am I getting old data?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, concurrency, isolation-level, postgresql-9.5

Today I discovered something weird on **PostgreSQL 9.5**. (I have no idea whether this is because of beta or not.) When I want to fetch data, I get old and deleted data from query. I then do `VACUUM FULL` and then I get proper data (which is empty).

Am I missing something here? What might be the reason that PostgreSQL returns old data?

Note: Autovacuum is `ON`.

Comment: Sounds like you hadn't COMMITted in another session & could therefore still see the data in a different session

Comment: @Phil BTW, to make clear let me add this: When I create new session and execute my query i get correct result. But PHP App always returns with wrong data (old). Resetting cache, resetting php-apcu did not solve the problem until VACUUM FULL. Is this still be an issue of UNCOMMITTED session?

Comment: Yeah, sounds transactional

Comment: @Phil I reproduced this issue by two different session without commit on one. Yes you're right. Cached session gets old data. Your answer is correct. Wow. Since years this is the first time i see such thing.

Comment: What isolation level is used?

Comment: @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ did you mean `default_transaction_isolation`? If yes, isolation is disabled. (#)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find the chapter [**Read Committed Isolation Level**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED) of the Postgres 9.5 manual instructive:

> *Read Committed* is the default isolation level in PostgreSQL. When a
>   transaction uses this isolation level, a `SELECT` query (without a
>   `FOR UPDATE/SHARE` clause) sees only data committed before the query began;
>   it **never sees either uncommitted data or changes committed during
>   query execution by concurrent transactions.**

Bold emphasis mine.

Until your transaction is committed, changes are not visible to other transactions. `VACUUM` has nothing to do with this, it only cleans up dead tuples after all transactions are finished with them.